# Guarding the Jewish camp in the wilderness

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, dor-hamidbar

Closely related to my previous question "[was-the-cloud-in-the-wilderness-war-proof](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/105745/was-the-g-ds-cloud-in-the-wilderness-war-proof)",

Camping in the wilderness would require forces to guard the camp 24/7. And if the cloud was protecting them, the cloud was canceled with the death of Aharon so the camp remained vulnerable.

However, I don't recall the Torah mentioning the requirement for guarding the camp against foreign attacks.

Is guarding the camp mentioned anywhere and if not, why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you got it right. It's not just that the Torah does not mention that they did guard the camp, It's almost written that they neglect camp guarding.

Right after Aharon died, the Israelits were vulnerable to attack - this vulnerability was used immediately.

פרשת חוקת

> ויסעו מקדש ויבאו בני ישראל כל העדה הר ההר ויאמר יהוה אל משה ואל אהרן
>   בהר ההר ...יאסף אהרן אל עמיו כי לא יבא אל הארץ אשר נתתי לבני ישראל...
>   ויראו כל העדה כי גוע אהרן ויבכו את אהרן שלשים יום כל בית ישראל   וישמע
>   הכנעני מלך ערד ישב הנגב ... וילחם בישראל וישב ממנו שבי

I assume, that after this event, the Israelits took care of proper perimeter defense !

Comment: Well, thank you for your support. But it's not an answer, you know. My question is why such important detail is missing from the story?

Comment: @AlBerko They didn't guard the camp, and were raided. It's all written.

Comment: So please give your thoughts on why it is not mentioned.

Comment: @AlBerko Why it's not mentioned that after the raid they kept their guard up? That's common sense...